# Associate "scalar" type with generic type

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking

Here's an example I've written:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Any, Protocol

class MyType(Protocol):
    scalar: Any

class MyIntegerType(MyType):
    scalar = int

class MyFloatType(MyType):
    scalar = float

T = TypeVar('T', bound=MyType)

class MyStack(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, items: list[T.scalar]) -> None:
        self.items = items

    def get_item(self, idx: int) -> T.scalar:
        return self.items[idx]

myfirststack = MyStack[MyIntegerType]([1, 2, 3])
print(myfirststack.get_item(0))

mysecondstack = MyStack[MyFloatType]([1., 2., 3.])
print(mysecondstack.get_item(0))
```

I have defined `MyType`, which is a `Protocol` which must have a `scalar` attribute. I have then made two classes:

- `MyIntegerType`, where `scalar` is `int`
- `MyFloatType`, where `scalar` is `float`

Then, I have a class `MyStack`, where `get_item` returns an item of the scalar type of the class's type.

So, from the example above, `myfirststack.get_item(0)` return an `int`, whereas `mysecondstack.get_item(0)` returns a `float`.

If I try type checking the above code, I get

```py
main.py:18: error: Name "T.scalar" is not defined  [name-defined]
main.py:21: error: Name "T.scalar" is not defined  [name-defined]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How can I rewrite it so that I can type the return value of `get_item`?